# Issues configuring Nodemailer 4.6.3 with Exchange 2010 (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, exchange-server-2010

My issue is with properly configuring Nodemailer with an Exchange 2010 email server on a Node.js application.

Because I'm not getting an authentication issue, which I do when using well-known services like Outlook365, I'm assuming the problem is with the host and/or security and port settings - I don't think I connect in the first place.

My config below -

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'https://email.<COMPANYNAME>.com/owa',
  port: '587',
  secure: false,
  auth: { 
    user: <USERNAME>, 
    pass: <PASSWORD>
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

It errors here on my Node app -

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Send error: ', error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent!');
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});
```

Here is the error from AWS EC2 logs -

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://email.<COMPANYNAME>.com/owa https://email.<COMPANYNAME>.com/owa:587
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://email.<COMPANYNAME>.com/owa',
  host: 'https://email.<COMPANYNAME>.com/owa',
  port: '587',
  command: 'CONN'
```

Nodemailer docs specify that the host "is the hostname or IP address to connect to (defaults to ‘localhost’)"

When I try more the conventional mail.COMPANYNAME.com my requests time out. Using the address clearly hits my server and returns errors in the verification/ sending steps that I've specified.

Again, the issue seems to be with my transporter configuration with Exchange 2010. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO's markdown syntax does not require backticks for code fences (and moreover, it doesn't even work with them). All you need to do is indent them, and they're now treated as code and displayed as such.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this question too. But I found the solution myself.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: 'smtp.office365.com',
         port: 587,
         secure: false,
         auth: {
            user: 'USER_NAME',
            pass: 'PASSWORD'
         }
      });
```

I used this configuration for sending email using node mailer from exchange or Office 365 server.